# Asynchronous network operations in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, ios5

Everywhere I look, I see people explicitly using queues or run loops to do network operations. Should I still do that in iOS 5, or should I use [`NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a) instead? Is this the preferred method of doing network operations in iOS >= 5?

Comment: Have a look at AFNetworking if you aren't already aware of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer for others' preference, but I rolled my own < os5, and I strongly prefer the block operation.  a) I'm never interested in intermediate results of the network operation, or the repetitive code to handle them, b) the block is retained, so I get fewer race conditions where some aspect of the delegate gets prematurely released, and c) I never get mixed up about what code is running when a particular operation finishes.

In short, it's a huge improvement in the NSURLConnection interface, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. For simple things, the new block-based API makes life a lot easier. However, compared to implementing the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods, you lose some control.

For example, it's not possible to cancel connections that have been initiated with this method, or to handle the response (e.g. for parsing headers) before all data is downloaded.

Comment: The method also lacks of progress notification, which is quite important for big download.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar to this with iOS 4 as well using GCD.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:blah returningResponse:response error:blah];
    //process response body here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //Update UI Code here
        self.textView.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data];

    });
});
```

The problem with this code and the code OP posted is that, once the connection is made, you cannot cancel them.
Canceling a request on viewDidDisappear goes a long way in improving the performance of your application. I talk extensively about this on the book [iOS PTL](http://iosptl.com/)

Second reason why you need a third party networking framework like MKNetworkKit or RestKit or the now defunct ASIHTTP is for authentication. Most web service require that you authenticate using a NSURLCredential (HTTP Basic or HTTP Digest or Windows NTLM or oAuth)

This alone will take a couple of days to do if you roll out your own code. Not that you shouldn't do it. But there is no need for one as all these third party frameworks are extensively used and the chances or bugs or performance issues in them is less compared to your own code.

Comment: Can't you cancel the `NSOperation` inside the `NSOperationQueue` that you send to `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` though?

Comment: NSOperation can be canceled. But that cannot necessarily cancel the operation. Only when you get delegate callbacks, you have an opportunity to cancel it. For example, if your NSURLConnection downloads 100MB of data and the user cancels it half way through, you can cancel it and perform cleanup in the didReceiveData: delegate callback. You cannot cancel an operation (at least without leaking memory) if you don't use the NSURLConnection delegates.

Comment: Just to expand on this: canceling an `NSOperation` does not actually stop it. It just marks it "canceled." Its up to your operation to do something with that fact. As Mugunth notes, there is no way for Cocoa to stop an arbitrary operation once it's started. That would trash memory management. So unless you implement various checks for `isCanceled` in your operation, `cancel` won't do much. You don't get cancelation for free.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [blog post](http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2013/08/managing-nested-asynchronous-callbacks-in-objective-c-using-reactive-cocoa/) that compares several approaches including **NSURLConnection**, **[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)**, and **ReactiveCocoa**.

#### ReactiveCocoa approach

If you want to get really fancy with asynchronous network calls, you can try out [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa). ReactiveCocoa allows you to define signals that represent each of your network requests. And it allows you to [chain multiple dependent network calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797081/chaining-dependent-signals-in-reactivecocoa).

```
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
// ...

-(RACSignal*)signalGetNetworkStep1 {
   NSURL* url = ...;
   return [RACSignal createSignal:^(RACDisposable *(id subscriber) {
      NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      AFJSONRequestOperation *operation1 = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
         [subscriber sendNext:JSON];
         [subscriber sendCompleted];
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
         [subscriber sendError:error];
      }];
      [operation1 start];
      return nil;
   }
}

-(void) yourMethod {
   [[self signalGetNetworkStep1] subscribeNext:^(id *x) {
      // perform your custom business logic
   }];
}
```