# Chaining dependent signals in ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

In ReactiveCocoa, if we chaining several dependent signals, we must use `subscribeNext:` for the next signal in the chain to receive the value previous signal produced (for example, a result of an asynchronous operation). So after a while, the code turns into something like this (unnecessary details are omitted):

```
RACSignal *buttonClickSignal = [self.logIn rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[buttonClickSignal subscribeNext:^(UIButton *sender) {    // signal from a button click
    // prepare data

    RACSignal *loginSignal = [self logInWithUsername:username password:password];    // signal from the async network operation

    [loginSignal subscribeNext:^void (NSDictionary *json) {
        // do stuff with data received from the first network interaction, prepare some new data

        RACSignal *playlistFetchSignal = [self fetchPlaylistForToken:token];         // another signal from the async network operation

        [playlistFetchSignal subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *json) {
            // do more stuff with the returned data
        }];

        // etc
    }];
}];
```

This ever-increasing nesting does not look much better than the non-reactive example that is given in the documentation:

```
[client logInWithSuccess:^{
    [client loadCachedMessagesWithSuccess:^(NSArray *messages) {
        [client fetchMessagesAfterMessage:messages.lastObject success:^(NSArray *nextMessages) {
            NSLog(@"Fetched all messages.");
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            [self presentError:error];
        }];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        [self presentError:error];
    }];
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    [self presentError:error];
}];
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better pattern of chaining dependent work in ReactiveCocoa?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is when the [RACStream](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h) and [RACSignal](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h) operators start really coming in handy. In your particular example, you can use `-flattenMap:` to incorporate results into new signals:

```
[[[buttonClickSignal
    flattenMap:^(UIButton *sender) {
        // prepare 'username' and 'password'
        return [self logInWithUsername:username password:password];
    }]
    flattenMap:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        // prepare 'token'
        return [self fetchPlaylistForToken:token];
    }]
    subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        // do stuff with the returned playlist data
    }];
```

If you don't need the results from any step, you can use `-sequenceMany:` or `-sequenceNext:` instead for a similar effect (but for a clearer expression of intent).

Comment: This solution works for me. I wrote a [blog article](http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2013/08/managing-nested-asynchronous-callbacks-in-objective-c-using-reactive-cocoa/) that explains this approach in more detail.

Comment: @Justin, would you mind elaborating more on the proper way to do error handling along the way?

Comment: @DogpatchTech You can use `-catch:` or `-catchTo:` for this. See [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439636/difference-between-catch-and-subscribeerror/19439687#19439687).

Comment: `-sequenceMany:` and `-sequenceNext:` are deprecated in 2.0+; `-sequenceMany:` is supposed to be replaced with `-flattenMap:` while ignoring the block arguments; `-sequenceNext:` is replaced by `-then:`. (See the changelog entry here: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#more-obvious-sequencing-operator)

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers how would you rewrite the above code if the `fetchPlaylistForToken` should have been called after `loginWithUsername` `completed` instead of sending the `next` event?

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli An operator like `-then:`, or `-materialize`, or something like that. That sounds like a code smell, though.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers can you use `concat`?