# Combine Multiple Network Requests with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: afnetworking, chaining, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm exploring ReactiveCocoa and trying to see whats possible. The issues i'm having is chaining a few network requests together.

I have 2 calls, the first gets a list of identifiers, then for each identifier I make a call to get data corresponding to that id and create a model object and return an array of the objects.

I'm using RACExtensions for AFNetworking to make the requests. Code looks something like this:

```objective-c
- (RACSignal *) identifersInfo
{
    return [[[[self identifiersSignal] flattenMap:^RACStream *(RACTuple *tuple) {
        RACTupleUnpack(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) = tuple;
        NSArray *identifiers = responseObject[@"Identifiers"];
        NSArray *requests = [self httpRequestsWithIdentifiers: identifiers];
        return [self.client rac_enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests: requests];
    }] collect] map:^id(RACTuple *tuple) {
        RACTupleUnpack(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) = tuple;
        Model *model = [[Model alloc] init];
        model.title = responseObject[@"Title"];
        model.description = responseObject[@"Description"];
        model.lastUpdated = responseObject[@"LastUpdated"];
        return model;
    }];
}
```

identifiersSignal method looks like this:

```objective-c
- (RACSignal *) identifiersSignal
{
    return [self.client rac_getPath: @"identifiers" parameters: nil];
}
```

This returns json dictionary which looks like:

```objective-c
{
  "Identifiers": [
    3,
    4,
    21
  ]
}
```

I'm actually mocking these calls at the moment and I know they work independently, I'm just trying to piece them together using ReacticeCocoa.

I can't figure out or find any decent samples on how this could be achieved using ReactiveCocoa, although I'm pretty confident it could be.

Comment: Check out the question "[Chaining dependent signals in ReactiveCocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797081/chaining-dependent-signals-in-reactivecocoa/15827396)" and the similar [section in the README](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#chaining-dependent-operations). There's also a wealth of information in the [Documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/tree/master/Documentation) folder, like an explanation of the [basic operators](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md).

Answer (score 0):

I had to look into the implementation of the AFNetworking extensions but I think you are misusing a some return values. I haven't tested but it seems like your code should look like this:

```
- (RACSignal *) identifersInfo {
    return [[[self identifiersSignal] map:^RACSignal *(RACTuple *tuple) {
        RACTupleUnpack(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) = tuple;
        NSArray *identifiers = responseObject[@"Identifiers"];
        NSArray *requests = [self httpRequestsWithIdentifiers: identifiers];
        return [self.client rac_enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests: requests];
    }] map:^Model*(id *reponseObject) {
        Model *model = [[Model alloc] init];
        // same as above
        return model;
    }];
}
```

It is a little misleading that `rac_getPath` returns a `RACTuple` as `rac_enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests` returns only a `RACStream` of the return objects. [AFURLConnectionOperation+RACSupport.m](https://github.com/CodaFi/AFNetworking-RACExtensions/blob/master/ReactiveAFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation%2BRACSupport.m#L29) The documentation in the header files should be improved with type information to get this straightened out.

Nice code, though.